# How to drive a counter with clock in testbench

Tags: vhdl

I wan to drive the counter in testbench.
The counter (`test_counter`) doesn't increment as expected. Could you explain why?

What I expected is The `test_counter` should increment by 1 every rising clock

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
entity testbench_keypad_v2 is
end entity;

-- testbench for keypad scan

architecture rtl OF testbench_keypad_v2 is

-- constants 
constant sys_clk_period : TIME := 100 ns;

-- signals 
signal sys_clk             :  std_logic;
signal led                  :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal knapp_in_1_n        :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

signal reset_n             :  std_logic;

constant default_value     :  unsigned(25 downto 0)           := 26d"200000";   -- 20ms

signal  test_counter        :   unsigned(25 downto 0)             := 26d"0";

component keypad_v1
 port (
    clk, reset_n            : in  std_logic;
    key_in                  : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    key_out                 : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   led_display              : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end component;

begin
i1 : keypad_v1
PORT MAP (
-- list connections between master ports and signals
clk                  =>    sys_clk,
led_display          =>    led,
key_in              =>    knapp_in_1_n,
reset_n              =>    reset_n
);
 
 

  -- Clock process
  process
  begin
    while true loop
      sys_clk <= not sys_clk;
      wait for sys_clk_period;  -- clock period is 100 ns
    end loop;
  end process;
  
reset: process
begin
    -- Reset at start up
   reset_n <= '0';
   wait for 5*sys_clk_period;
   -- Target running
   reset_n <= '1';
   wait; -- test case 5
   -- ett tomt “WAIT;” stannar processen, eftersom det finns inget villkor
end process;


counter_cases : process(test_counter)
begin
    
    if rising_edge(sys_clk) then

        test_counter <= test_counter + 1;

        
    end if;
    
end process;


  
Test_cases : process
begin
   --- Test case 1
   knapp_in_1_n <= "0000"; -- Key not pressed
   wait for 200001*sys_clk_period/2;

   knapp_in_1_n <=  "0010"; -- Key pressed
   wait for 133334*3*sys_clk_period/2;

   knapp_in_1_n <=  "0000"; -- Key not pressed
   wait for 600013*sys_clk_period;
   

   -- stable state
   for i in 1 to 2 loop
     knapp_in_1_n <=  "1000"; -- Key pressed
     wait for 400007*sys_clk_period/2;
     -- Test case 3
     knapp_in_1_n <=  "0000"; -- Key not pressed
     wait for 1200029*sys_clk_period/2;
   end loop;
    
    
    knapp_in_1_n <=  "1000"; -- Key pressed
    wait for 285813*sys_clk_period/2;
    -- Test case 3
    knapp_in_1_n <=  "0000"; -- Key not pressed
    wait for 270250*sys_clk_period;
          
   wait;                  -- end the stimulus
end process;

  

end rtl;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*doesn't increment as expected*" Please edit your question (don't add in comments) and add numeric data for (a) what `test_counter` actually does and (b) what you expected it to do.

Comment: @TonyM The `test_counter` should increment by every rising clock

Comment: the counter_cases process has a sensitivity list with one element, `test_counter` when it's sensitivity list should have `sys_clk` instead. Also note the period of the clock is actually have the period, the time before each transition. Your code is hard to read for the use of gratuitous new lines and lack of indentation.

Comment: @user16145658 Thank you for explanation. "the period of the clock is actually have the period, the time before each transition" Could you explain this in detail?

Comment: Sarah L. Harris, David Harris, in Digital Design and Computer Architecture, 2022. 3.5.2 System Timing "The clock period or cycle time, Tc, is the time between rising edges of a repetitive clock signal." That implies an intervening falling edge.

Comment: @user16145658, "*Your code is hard to read for the use of gratuitous new lines and lack of indentation. *" The VHDL is indented and spaced reasonably. Are you sure you don't just mean presented the way you prefer to have it? There are minimums that most agree should be implemented, as they have been here, but some descend into it being a sort of beauty contest.

Comment: @user16145658 I am trying to indent it now. See the update. But I am still confusing about what you mean "intervening falling edge". I can't indent in here stackoverflow. The tab will quit me in stackoverflow

Comment: You can leave the indentation as it is, it looks sufficient. You can get rid of all the blank lines, though, that just cause unnecessary scrolling, especially when read on a smartphone.

Comment: A clock period would include both a 0 -> 1 and and 1 -> 0 transition, a full clock cycle.  Your unlabelled clock process (which can loop without the loop statement) only contains one assignment to sys_clk in the interval defined by `wait for sys_clk_period` which defines the time between any transition. `clock: process begin sys_clk <= not sys_clk; wait for sys_clk_period/2; end process;` would define that half period. Because you require -2008 (`26d"0"`) you could use a procedure call to std.env.finish to end simulation instead of the final wait in process Test_cases.

Comment: @user16145658 Could you write you clock in the answer section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `test_counter` clocked process is sensitive to the test counter itself.

It should be sensitive to the clock. See the corrected form below.

The process sensitivity list states which signals would have to change (have an event) for the process to be re-evaluated. This process is the only thing that changes `test_counter`. So that process can't be sensitive to `test_counter`, sat there waiting for a change on it that'll never come.

```
--counter_cases : process(test_counter)
counter_cases : process(sys_clk) is
begin
  if rising_edge(sys_clk) then

    test_counter <= test_counter + 1;

  end if;
end process;
```